# GA4 Data API Architecture / Reporting for AB Testing

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Problem: Implementing GA4 / Architecture / API concepts around AB Testing without having to user_scope dimensions into swimlanes.

Currently firing `gtag('event', 'experiment', { exp_bucket });` and have `exp_bucket` configured as an event dimension. I can see and get to this data in the Custom Explore UI but I can't seem to recreate that User segment or other view in the GA4 Beta Data API. All I get back are User Totals / Event Counts and 0's for funnel steps etc

```js
makeRequest(`https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/${propertyId}:runReport`, {
    dateRanges: [{ startDate: '2023-03-20', endDate: 'today' }],
    dimensions: [{ name: `customEvent:exp_bucket` }],
    metrics: [
      { name: 'totalUsers' },
      { name: 'newUsers' },
      { name: 'bounceRate' },
      { name: 'addToCarts' },
      { name: 'checkouts' },
      { name: 'totalRevenue' },
      { name: 'totalPurchasers' },
      { name: 'ecommercePurchases' },
      { name: 'firstTimePurchaserConversionRate' },
      { name: 'averagePurchaseRevenuePerPayingUser' },
    ],
  });
```

[image: event scoped dimension report]

Is there a way I can adjust my data pull and/or something I could consider changing in the event / dimension architecture? The only thing I can think of is create like "ab_test_lane_[1|2|3|4|5]" as a user dimension and then map each active experiment into a lane but then I have complexity of mapping live experiments to singular lanes to avoid conflict etc...

Comment: Do you mean that you create audience in GA4 explorer report and trying to re-create in through GA4 Data API?

Comment: No it's currently a segment in the GA4 explorer report